# getting title of citation with regex

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I am not so extremely familiar with regex but I would like to extract the title of a paper from a citation:
The title is in between the year (for example 1991 in the 1st citation) and the following dot in the sentence. I make it here in italics.

> "1Moulds J.M., Nickells M.W., Moulds J.J., et al. (1991) *The C3b/C4b
> receptor is recognized by the Knops, McCoy, Swain-langley, and York
> blood group antisera*. J. Exp. Med.5:1159-63."
>
> "2Rochowiak A., Niemir Z.I. (2010) *The structure and role of CR1
> complement receptor in pathology*. Pol. Merkur Lekarski. 28:84–88."
>
> "3WHO. Geneva: WHO; 2018. World Malaria Report 2018".

The citation are stored in a data frame (df) in the column "citation"
Output:

```
The C3b/C4b receptor is recognized by the Knops, McCoy, Swain-langley, and York blood group antisera

The structure and role of CR1 complement receptor in pathology
```

I wrote a regex which looks like this:

```
df$citation = sub('[^"]*?)', "", df$citation)
df$citation = sub("\\..*", "", df$citation)
```

Any advice on how to make it one line only?
In addition, it would be good to have a regex which if it does not find the year in parenthesis such as for the third citation it will delete the citation. Possible to do this?

Comment: hi, I edited, can you make it open again please?

Comment: Now, it is unclear, what are the rules for the pattern? Where should matching start/end and more importantly why?

Comment: It is indicated in the input/output. It should match and keep whatever is in between the year in parenthesis and the following dot

Comment: Sure, I can edit the text to explain this

Comment: Well, this is something missing in the question now. I think given these requirements, you may use `sub("^.*?\\b(?:19|20)\\d{2}\\)\\s*([^.]+).*", "\\1", df$citation, perl=TRUE)`

Comment: thank you, I will try it out. By the way, I have one more question, which I added. Is it possible to use sub either to match a string or delete a citation if it does not find a match?

Comment: Yes, `"(?s)^.*?\\b(?:19|20)\\d{2}\\)\\s*([^.]+).*|.+"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your set of requirements, you can use

```
sub("^.*?\\b(?:19|20)\\d{2}\\)\\s*([^.]+).*", "\\1", df$citation, perl=TRUE)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7NkCHr/1/)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars, other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\b(?:19|20)\d{2}` - word boundary, `19` or `20` and any two digits
- `\)`  - a `)` char
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `([^.]+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than `.`
- `.*` - any 0+ chars, other than line break chars, as many as possible.